# Что такое избыточность дискового пространства?

Tags: hdd

Здравствуйте, никак не могу понять, что такое избыточность дискового пространства. Я искал в яндексе, но нашел пару фраз. А так, хорошего пояснения не увидел. Помогите ссылкой или поясните, что это за штука такая. Спасибо.

Comment: Дабы не дублировать, ответ я уже написал к тому времени, как вопрос закрыли, посмотрите [здесь](http://hashcode.ru/questions/109791/что-такое-избыточность-дискового-пространства}

Answer (score 2):

Отказоустойчивость массива достигается за счет избыточности информации, сохраняемой на жестких дисках, то есть часть емкости дискового пространства отводится для служебных целей, становясь недоступной для пользователя. Избыточная информация может либо размещаться на специально выделенном диске, либо распределяться между всеми дисками массива. Способов формирования избыточной информации довольно много. Простейший из них — полное дублирование (или зеркалирование) — имеет 100-процентную избыточность. Для снижения избыточности (увеличения объема полезного дискового пространства) используются различные математические методы типа вычисления четности или применения кодов с коррекцией ошибок.

Это оно?